# Probability of same observations in two independent samples of different size

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

My goal is to find the probability of matching observations from two draws of different sizes.

Say I have an urn of $N$ balls identified $1, 2, 3, ..., N$. I draw $k$ balls from the urn without replacement. I then return those balls to the urn. I then sample $w$ balls where $w\geq k$. Say we then have $v$ matches of balls where $0 \le v \le k$. What is the probability of getting $v$ matches?

For the scenario where we draw $k$ balls twice, the probability of $v$ matches is $p = C(k,v)\times C(N−k,k−v) ∕C(N,k)$ based on [(Anselin and Li, 2020)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/gean.12237).

This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1175483/resampling-probability/1187045#1187045) seems to be the closest to my question. But doesn't quite get to it.

Additionally, [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3209949/expected-proportion-of-distinct-observations-when-sampling-n-observations-with) seems that it may be useful to some degree.

Comment: This is a simple hypergeometric probability. In your notation, the answer is $\dfrac{C(k,v)C(n-k,w-v)}{C(n,w)}$.  In mine  $\dfrac{{k\choose v}{n-k\choose w-v}}{{n \choose w}}$

Comment: Thank you so much! And for the condition that $w < k$ would we return to the original formula $C(k ,v)C(n-k, k-v)/C(n,k)$?

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3504907/573047). It doesn't matter if $w \ge k$ or $w \lt k$, you get the same result. Note that you can exchange $w$ and $k$ in Henry's formula and obtain the same value.

Comment: @thus__ No.  If $w < k$ you have exactly the same $\dfrac{{k\choose v}{n-k\choose w-v}}{{n \choose w}}$ formula, but it only produces positive results when $\max(0,k+w-n) \le v \le \min(w,k)$